# How should I handle index maintenance on partitioned tables in Azure SQL DB?

Tags: sql-server, index, partitioning, azure

let's start saying that i have no experience with partitioned tables and i'm not quite sure how to handle index maintenance (periodically Rebuild / Reorganize, if needed, to reduce index fragmentation). Consider my scenario:

we have 3 tables partitioned by year-month on the same PRIMARY filegroup, as Azure forces you to do, containing historical data with a retention of 2 years. Two of these tables have one aligned clustered index each, the remaining one has one aligned NON clustered index. Every day, a lot of data (around 150K rows) comes into these tables and, since we don't need to archieve it, once per month every partition that contains data older than X gets truncated and merged.

I've found very little evidence around the Web about this topic, and i couldn't get a satisfying post / thread that fully explains what is needed to do. I heard that, thanks to the truncation of the entire partition, there is no need to periodically maintain the aligned indexes, is that true?

Thank you.

Comment: Your link refers to mainly columnstore indexes, but it seems that your indexes are b-tree.  Bplease clarify (always add details to the post, and just a pointer in comment). Anyhow, start with what it is that you want to achieve by index maintenance. Reduce jumping back and forth in the data file? Manage free space on pages? Or align min/max values for your rowgroups based on some certain columns (columnstore indexes)? Based on that info, we can start a discussion. :-)

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Hi, i have updated the post including some details. I also removed the link as it might be deceiving.

Comment: We're still lacking details. I.e., what exactly are you expecting to achieve/adress: Reduce jumping back and forth in the data file? Manage free space on pages? Do you have any evidence that you have external or internal fragmentation in the first place (sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats will tell you)?

Comment: "*i'm not quite sure how to handle index maintenance (periodically Rebuild / Reorganize, if needed, to reduce index fragmentation)*" - You don't. It's unnecessary and wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

> I heard that, thanks to the truncation of the entire partition, there
> is no need to periodically maintain the aligned indexes, is that true?

Partition level `TRUNCATE` is unrelated to index maintenance, AFAIK. Each partition is wholly contained so truncating a partition does not affect indexes of other partitions or their maintenance needs.

Appropriate index maintenance, partitioned or not, depends on many factors. Below is an excerpt from [Index maintenance in Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16#index-maintenance-in--and-):

> For most types of storage used in Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL
> Managed Instance, there is no difference in performance between
> sequential I/O and random I/O. This reduces the impact of index
> fragmentation on query performance.

Consequently, index maintenance for the purpose of reducing fragmentation has minimal impact in the Azure SQL Database world. The same can generally be said for most on-prem SQL Server instances using modern storage subsystems.

Another consideration from the same documentation topic:

> Index maintenance may be required to increase page density and reduce
> used space in the database, and thus stay within the size limit of the
> pricing tier. This avoids having to scale up to a higher pricing tier
> with a higher size limit.

I'll add that a higher page density also improves buffer efficiency and requires less IO for the same amount of data, thus improving query performance.

I suggest you bother with index maintenance only if you observe low page density. Assuming data in historical partitions are not updated, you could incorporate partition-level index maintenance as part of your monthly sliding window maintenance to maximize density:

- `TRUNCATE` and `MERGE` oldest partition to purge old data
- `SPLIT` function to create boundary for future month
- Rebuild previous month partition with fill factor 100 to maximize density
- Update statistics so that table-level stats reflect data removed by `TRUNCATE`.

Consider row or page compression (especially for infrequently used historical partitions) to reduce storage, IO, and memory requirements.

4.5M rows per month is likely only a few GB of memory/storage so I wouldn't bother with index maintenance of the current month partition.